# delete button is deleting the last inserted row in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete_dayOff'])) {
 $DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM dayoff WHERE id = '$_POST[hidden]'";
 mysqli_query($db,$DeleteQuery);
 };

// display records

$select_employee = "SELECT * FROM dayoff";
$result = $db->query($select_employee);
 ?>
<table>
<div id="Day-off Employees">
<?php
     echo "<table><caption>Day-off Employees</caption><tr>
    <th>Employee First Name</th>
    <th>Employee Last Name</th>
    <th>Day-Off</th>

    </tr>";

    echo "<form action=dayoff.php method=post>";

     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

         echo "<tr>";

         echo "<td>" . $row["employeefname"]. "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row["employeelname"]. "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row["date"]. "</td>";


echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden  value=" . $row["id"].  " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input  type=submit   name=delete_dayOff value=delete  >" . " </td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</form";


echo "</table>";


?>
```

I'm using the same exact script on another page and it's working perfectly. `id` is autonumber primary key int, not null in mysql.

If I press delete, it always deletes the last inserted row in mysql, or the newest row.

If i echo the content of hidden button, it is correct, but if i press the delete button, it deletes the wrong row, why?

Comment: sorry for any missing html tag, i just copied the part you need to see

Comment: place your form tags inside your `while` loop and you really should quote your inputs. That has been known to have adverse effects. Look at your HTML source also. You're also open to an SQL injection here.

Comment: Your $_POST[hidden] won't be evaluated properly in your `$DeleteQuery`. You should change it to `$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM dayoff WHERE id = '" . (int) $_POST['hidden'] . "'" ;`. This is also one way to ensure that the id in an int to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I hand coded the same type of script last week and had the same problem. Anyway, you've been given comments/answers. Ask those guys below now, I am moving on; good luck.

Comment: @Andrew they're voting me down because they think i forgot to put form inside while but i didn't, tried didnt work so somehow i posted this typo here, your answer is the one that fixed it, but since you have more rep than the guy who answered it, not gonna ask you to answer, thanks so much though.

Comment: This code opens you to a terrible SQL injection. Look into prepared statements; http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php Your attribute values also should be encapsulated in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have one and only form although you want to be able to delete a single row. You should have as many form that you have rows.

Instead of putting your form tags outside your while loop, you should put them inside, this way, you'll have many forms.

The trouble with having only one form is that you named the hidden field with the same name so it will take the last one.

do

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
     ...
    echo '<td><form ...><input hidden...><input type="submit"...></form></td>';
    ...
}
```

Comment: and what about the other tag?

Comment: oh yes sorry I forgot the closing form tag, I edited my answer

Comment: actually in my code i tried putting it inside, and didnt work, it was a combination of your answer and andrews that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST[hidden]` should be `$_POST['hidden']`;

```
 $DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM dayoff WHERE id = '$_POST['hidden']'";
```

Comment: I think the $_POST['hidden'] won't be evaluated. You should put braces around it like `$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM dayoff WHERE id = '{$_POST['hidden']}'";`